# MATLAB: Save figure with default name

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am running a matlab-script that produces a figure. To save this figure I use:

```
print(h_f,'-dpng','-r600','filename.png')
```

What this means is that if I don't change filename for each time I run the script, the figure filename.png will be overwritten. 
Is there a way to save a figure to a default name, e.g. untitled.png, and then when the script is run twice it will make a new figure untitled(1).png instead of overwriting the original one?

Comment: why not creating a string before the command `print` ? With string = 'filenamexx.png' and then `print(arg1,arg2,arg3,string)`

Comment: I strongly suggest incorporating some information in the filename that allows the user to identify what's contained in the images. If a file has the same name, it should have the same information. Having to sift through `{filename.png, filename (1).png, filename (2).png, ..., filename (n).png}` in order figure out what is contained in the files is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new *filename* based on the number of existing files

```
defaultName = 'untitled';
fileName = sprintf('%s_%d.png', defaultName, ...
   length(dir([defaultName '_*.png'])));

print(h_f,'-dpng','-r600', fileName)
```

Add a folder path to your `dir` search path if the files aren't located in your current working directory.

This will create a 0-index file name list

```
untitled_0.png
untitled_1.png
untitled_2.png
untitled_3.png
...
```

---

You could also use [`tempname`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tempname.html) to generate a long random name for each iteration. Unique for most cases, see section [Limitations](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tempname.html).

```
print(h_f,'-dpng','-r600', [tempname(pwd) '.png'])
```

The input argument ([`pwd`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pwd.html) in the example) is needed if you do not want to save the files in your [TEMPDIR](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tempdir.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
for jj=1:N
   name_image=sscanf('filename','%s') ;
   ext=sscanf('.png','%s') ;


   %%do your stuff


   filename=strcat(name_image,num2str(jj),ext);

   print(h_f,'-dpng','-r600',filename)


end
```

If you want to execute your script multiple time (because you don't want to use a "for") just declare a variable (for example `jj`that will be incremented at the end of the script:

```
jj=jj+1;
```

Be careful to don't delete this variable and, when you start again your script, you will use the next value of `jj` to compose the name of the new image.
This is just an idea