# Save data in text files with a concatened name

Tags: matlab

I am loading my files into matlab. 
I import a .txt file using `importdata`, then I process the files and then I would like to save some results in different text files. 
For example if I process: 
`'toto.txt'`

At the end I would like to save 2 texts files name : 
`'toto_part1.txt'` 
`'toto_part2.txt'` 
 and so on if I have more than 2 parts.

Any ideas? 
Thank you

Comment: Perhaps the first part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39900512/3635260) could help you on the way ...

Comment: You can use the matlab concatenation (like `[toto_part',num2str(n),'.txt]`) in a loop, where `n` is the loop variable (for instance `for n=1:3` , ...)

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how to use this solution. Where do I write my matrix that takes the name toto_part....txt ? Also how do I write this into a .txt file ? thank you very much @AlexanderKorovin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you did not provide an example I will try to explain my comment under your question. Let we have a text file with text and numerical data:

`toto.txt`

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1    2    3
4    5    6
```

Next we use the `importdata` function to load file and separate numerical and text data:

```
tmp = importdata('toto.txt'); % load file to a struct
matrix = tmp.data; % save data to a matrix
```

And now we save some data (for example, columns):

```
% save all columns in separated files
for n=1:size(matrix,2)
      out = matrix(:,n); % extract n-th column 
      % save in ascii format with tabs separator
      save(['toto',num2str(n),'.txt'],'out','-ascii', '-tabs');
end
```

Here you can see an example of the string concatenation: `['toto',num2str(n),'.txt']`